# The argument passed to on_release parameter in kivy list for all widgets is same when the code runs. why? and how to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

i am currently trying to make a youtube interface which filters the youtube algorithm so you dont waste your time in entertainment and i have come across a problem i don't know how to solve because of my lack of knowledge

**Problem:** the argument in the function for on_release in list item is same for all the list items (i.e, the on_release function's argument of the last list item is used for all the list items somehow)

**Me selecting channel 1 (better ideas)**
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv5b2.png)

**Me getting "Learn japanese channel" instead of "better ideas" channel**
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oymMY.png)

getting the correct channel name is important as then i will be able to scrape video information of that channel

**code which i used to add the items to the channel list**:

```
    def on_start(self):
        channel_logos_dir = "static/channel_images/"
        channel_logos_list = os.listdir(channel_logos_dir)

        for channel_logo_name in channel_logos_list:
            channel_name = channel_logo_name[:-4]
            print(channel_name)
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source=channel_logos_dir + channel_logo_name)
            item = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text=channel_name, on_release=lambda x: self.chan_page(channel_name))
            item.add_widget(image)
            self.root.ids.subs_scr_id.ids.subs_id.add_widget(item)
```

folder heirarchy for images:

```
static
    |--  channel_images
            |--    Better Ideas.jpg
            |--    Krish Naik.jpg
            |--    Learn Japanese with JapanesePod101.com.jpg
```

Here the channel name for all the items in list is the channel name of the last item

```
on_release=lambda x: self.chan_page(channel_name)
```

**My entire code:**

```
import os
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarListItem, ImageLeftWidget
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

Window.size = (300, 500)

channels = {"Krish Naik":"https://www.youtube.com/user/krishnaik06",
            "Learn Japanese with JapanesePod101.com":"https://www.youtube.com/c/japanesepod101",
            "Better Ideas":"https://www.youtube.com/c/BetterIdeas/"}

screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    HomeScreen:
        id: home_src_id
    SubscriptionScreen:
        id: subs_scr_id
    ChannelScreen:
        id: channel_scr_id

<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'YouTube'
            left_action_items: [["youtube", lambda x: app.navigation_draw()]]
            right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: app.search_popup()]]
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "youtube-subscription"
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}   
                on_press: root.manager.current = "subscriptions"

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Go to subscriptions using top menu'
            halign: 'center'

    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'profile'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}   
        on_press: root.manager.current = "subscriptions"

<SubscriptionScreen>:
    name: 'subscriptions'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'YouTube'
            left_action_items: [["youtube", lambda x: app.navigation_draw()]]
            right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: app.search_popup()]]
            MDIconButton:
                icon: "youtube-subscription"
                md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}   
                on_press: root.manager.current = "profile"
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: subs_id

<ChannelScreen>
    name: 'channelPage'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            id: channel_name
            left_action_items: [["keyboard-backspace", lambda x: app.navigation_draw()]]
            right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.search_popup()]]
    
        MDTabs:
            id: tabs
            on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
    
<Tab>
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: vids_id
                """


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SubscriptionScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ChannelScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
subscription_screen = SubscriptionScreen(name='subscriptions')
sm.add_widget(subscription_screen)
sm.add_widget(ChannelScreen(name='channelPage'))
sm.current = "home"


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.current_channel = 'Krish Naik'

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        channel_logos_dir = "static/channel_images/"
        channel_logos_list = os.listdir(channel_logos_dir)

        for channel_logo_name in channel_logos_list:
            channel_name = channel_logo_name[:-4]
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source=channel_logos_dir + channel_logo_name)
            item = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text=channel_name, on_release=lambda x: self.chan_page(channel_name))
            item.add_widget(image)
            self.root.ids.subs_scr_id.ids.subs_id.add_widget(item)


        self.root.ids.channel_scr_id.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(title=f"Videos"))
        self.root.ids.channel_scr_id.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(title=f"Playlists"))
        self.root.ids.channel_scr_id.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(title=f"Community"))

    def on_tab_switch(
        self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        '''Called when switching tabs.

        :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
        :param instance_tab: <__main__.Tab object>;
        :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
        :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
        '''
        for i in range(20):
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source="static/channel_images/Krish Naik.jpg")
            item = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text="krish naik", on_release=lambda x: self.chan_page(channel_name))
            item.add_widget(image)
            instance_tab.ids.vids_id.add_widget(item)

    # @staticmethod
    def chan_page(self,channel_name):
        self.root.current = "channelPage"
        self.root.ids.channel_scr_id.ids.channel_name.title = channel_name
        self.current_channel = channel_name




DemoApp().run()
```

**My output:**

```
C:\Users\rahim\PycharmProjects\yt_filter\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/rahim/PycharmProjects/yt_filter/mian.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\rahim\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-07-01_91.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\rahim\PycharmProjects\yt_filter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\rahim\PycharmProjects\yt_filter\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06 (installed at "C:\Users\rahim\PycharmProjects\yt_filter\venv\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.13596 Compatibility Profile Context 20.10.35.02 27.20.1034.6'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ATI Technologies Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 8 Graphics'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Loader      ] using a thread pool of 2 workers
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<StringProperty name=text>" of object "<__main__.Tab object at 0x000002D50A02F120>" has been set, it will be removed in a future version
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Thank you for your time**

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error when using a `lambda` within a loop. The `lambda` function references a variable that is scoped within the loop, and when the `lambda` is executed, that variable has the last value that it was assigned in the loop. A fix is to create a new argument to the `lambda` function, like this:

```
        item = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text=channel_name, on_release=lambda x, y=channel_name: self.chan_page(y))
```